# Inserting Data into sqllite database with Corona SDK simulator

Tags: sqlite, insert, lua, coronasdk

I can query data in an SQLlite database using the corona SDK simulator but can not insert or delete data.  I am running the latest public release of the Corona SDK.  Here is the code.  It compiles fine but the insert command simply will not work.  Here is the code for the main.lua:

```
local sqlite3 = require "sqlite3"

local function setUpDatabase(dbName)

local path = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
local file = io.open( path, "r" )

if ( file == nil ) then
    -- copy the database file if doesn't exist
    local pathSource     = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.ResourceDirectory )
    local fileSource     = io.open( pathSource, "r" )
    local contentsSource = fileSource:read( "*a" )

    local pathDest = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    local fileDest = io.open( pathDest, "w" )
    fileDest:write( contentsSource )

    io.close( fileSource )
    io.close( fileDest )
end

local gameDB = system.pathForFile(dbName, system.DocumentsDirectory)
local dbNew = sqlite3.open( gameDB )

return dbNew

end

function loadData()
    local sql = "select * from projects"
    local projects = {}

    for a in db:nrows(sql) do
        projects[#projects+1] =
        {
        id = a.id,
        name = a.name,
        category = a.category,
        rating = a.rating
        }
    end

    return projects
end

function insertData(n, c, r)
    local sql = "insert into projects (name, category, rating) values ('" .. n .. "', '" .. c .. "', " .. r .. ")"
   db:exec(sql)
end

function deleteData(id)
    local sql = "delete from projects where id = " .. tostring(id)
    db:exec(sql)
end

function updateData(id, col, v)
    local sql = "update projects set " .. col .. " = '" .. v .. "' where id = " .. tostring(id)
    db:exec(sql)
end

db = setUpDatabase("mydatabase.sqlite")
insertData("Horse Crazy", "Game", 2)

deleteData(3)
--updateData(4, "name", "Ralph")
--updateData(4, "category", "Dog")
--updateData(4, "rating", 4)

local data = loadData()

for x = 1, #data do
    print (data[x].id, data[x].name, data[x].category, data[x].rating)
end
```

Comment: It works fine for me as it is. I did not change anything. I created a "mydatabase.sqlite" db in DocumentsDirectory with a "projects" table with (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, category TEXT, rating INTEGER). What works for me sometimes is to isolate the problem, create a clean main.lua project and test it there, if it works then the problem comes from somewhere else. Hope it helps!

Comment: What version of Corona SDK simulator are you using.  I have the feeling that somehow their is an issue with where the resource directory is and the insert, update and delete statements are not finding the database.   Wonder if this might have something to do with running the SDK on Windows XP Pro 64 bit.  I'll try it on another computer.   If anyone has other ideas please let me know.  Glad to know the code is working! - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out after having same problem for a while.
You have to replace this line

```
local sql = [[delete from projects WHERE ID = ']]..id..[[';]]
db:exec(sql)
```

make sure id is a number otherwise simply make it a number by adding this before first line:

```
id=id*1
```

Comment: for simplicity sakes, you can use " instead of  [[]] for a single line sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is system.DocumentsDirectory files in your simulator are read, but this files are not included in your device system.DocumentsDirectory. You have to create this file again when the app is running on your device.